# PowerBI Embedded Export Data fails with "ExportDataFailed: Error generating details table"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Using `powerbi-client 2.6.1`:

```
let report; // set earlier
report.getPages().then(pages => {
  const page = pages[0]
  page.getVisuals().then(visuals =>
    visuals[0].exportData().then(console.log)
  )
})
```

This code throws an error that looks like this:

```
{
  "message":"ExportDataFailed",
  "detailedMessage":"Error generating details table",
  "level":3,
  "errorCode":undefined,
  "technicalDetails":{
    "requestId": undefined,
    "errorInfo": undefined
  }
}
```

I'm sure that the given page/visual are loaded, as they have finished rendering in the embed iframe.  The visual in question has fewer than 1,000 rows so it's not the data limit.

Inspecting the [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/blob/v2.6.1/src/visualDescriptor.ts#L137), I expect to see a POST request to be initiated when I call `visual.exportData()` but my network tab shows nothing.

Where is this error coming from?

### More debugging information

- The visual in question is a basic table with non-aggregated metrics.
- Selecting the "export data" menu item in the ellipsis menu succeeds.
- The error message suggests to me that the error logger blew up

Answer (score 0):

What is the visual type you are trying to export data from?

Please note that export-data API works only if the visual use basic aggregations, and it doesn't work if the visihave measure.

Please read [export-data docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Export-Data) and make sure you don't have some of the limitations described in the wiki.

In addition, you can do this sanity check: Go to powerbi.com, open your report there. then try to export to CSV. if it works for you, exportData API should work for you.